# Oracle database query tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, hiveql

I have a big sql query and its difficult to manage, what I need help ifI can do anything like -

store the inner queries in variables and use variable as reference in the outer queries example

```
var1 = select * from customer
var2 = select * from product
var3= select custid from var1

and finally

select a.customername,b*,c* from var1 as a, var2 as b , var3 as c  where a.custid = c.c_id and     
a.custid = b.custid
```

Note I am not a database person, I am a java programmer

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is CTE- common table expression.

Comment: Variables in SQL are data. Data is processed, it is not part of the language (without dynamic SQL). You may use Common Table Expression (CTE), which is called subquery factoring clause in Oracle, to provide name to your subquery and access it as a general table/view (improving query readability and code reuse).

Comment: Thanks Pankaj and Astenx, thats exactly I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTEs (Common Table Expressions) to simplify the main query. For example, your query can be rephrased as:

```
with
a as (
  -- big complex query #1 here
),
b as (
  -- big complex query #2 here
),
c as (
  -- big complex query #3 here
)
select a.customername, b.*, c.* -- the main query starts at this line
from a
join b on b.custid = a.custid
join c on c.c_id = a.custid
```

The main query can have references to any of the CTEs (`a`, `b`, or `c`). Each CTE can alse have references to the previously defined CTEs; in your example, the third one will probably reference the first one.